# Why brackets "()" are not getting underlined in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have searched through the net, but I didn't find any solution for this.

I want underline for brackets also.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>hhh(9)</a>
```

Comment: It is more a font drawing issue. The brackets are larger in height than a character. Adding an underline to it is visually ugly imo. You can add some spacing below it with a border styling as a workaround.

Comment: This is likely browser-specific - a screenshot may be helpful here. `border-bottom` might be an alternative solution.

Comment: They are underlined in Windows Chrome (with brackets slightly jutting out under the line) but not Mac (imo they look fine on Mac)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because in a recent version of Chrome ([version 64](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5631679087509504)), they seem to have enabled `text-decoration-skip-ink` in the default user agent styles and have set it to `auto`. To remove this, add this to your CSS (will apply to all styles):

```
* {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}
```

[More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink) about it on MDN:

> The text-decoration-skip-ink CSS property specifies how overlines and underlines are drawn when they pass over glyph ascenders and descenders.
>
> ```
> /* Single keyword */
> text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
> text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
>
> /* Global keywords */
> text-decoration-skip: inherit;
> text-decoration-skip: initial;
> text-decoration-skip: unset;
> ```

***Here's an example using your code above:***

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>hhh(9)</a>
```

Comment: Thank you @DanielJames . That's a useful info . :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use border bottom if you want the bracket to have underline ^^

```css
a{
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom : 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>hhh(9)</a>
```

Comment: That will be problem when word count more than one.

Comment: This doesn't address the actual issue with the underline.

Answer (score 2):

It **is** underlined.

Look at the example below. Would you argue that the character `p` is not underlined?

```css
a {
  text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>hhh(9)</a><br>
<a href="#">[a][a]</a><br>
<a href="#">ppap</a><br>
```

If you really need a line below those characters, use border.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<a href='#'>hhh(9)</a><br>
<a href="#">[a][a]</a><br>
<a href="#">ppap</a><br>
```

Comment: Thank you @YongQuan and i will not argue. My requirement is to get brackets underlined.:)

Comment: For future readers, a better answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483800/why-brackets-are-not-getting-underlined-in-css/#50484081). At the time of writing, [the solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-skip-ink) given by the answer is still in `Editor's Draft` by MDN standard.

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are not underline just because of recent browser like chrome enable   text-decoration-skip-ink

You have to write this shortcode in your CSS

```
* {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: none;
}

a{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

<a href="#">underline text with () brackets</a>
```